# ActivityGroup is Deprecated

Tags: android, logout, tabbar, activitygroup

I am making android application containing three tabs.. On third tab there is login screen..

when i click on login button ...i want to replace the activity with activity containing list view and logout button....

Previously i was using Activity Group to replace the activity..But activity Group is now deprecated..

Now how can i replace the activity under third tab??

I am using these code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MyApp.this, LoginPage.class);

                    replaceContentVieww("activity4", intent);



  public void replaceContentVieww(String id, Intent newIntent) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


View view = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(id,newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)).getDecorView(); 
                            setContentView(view);


                    }
```

There is link from which i came to know this [class has been deprecated.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityGroup.html)

Comment: did u get the output..? i Facing same problem

Comment: You have to use the Fragment and FragmentManager

Comment: do u have any reference or example code or link..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should use Fragment and FragmentManager in the Compatibility Package

http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html

download it using the ADT, then go to the samples here 
extras/android/compatibility/v4/samples/

Comment: how can i use it in my app? There is any sample code to do it

Comment: I have put the samples path in my answer, for more information on fragments please refer to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html

Comment: It's not a link for sample . Can you give me complete link for this

Comment: it is not a link, it is a path on your pc, if you downloaded the Compatibility Package, go to your android sdk directory and from there go to "extras/android/compatibility/v4/samples/"

Comment: i have downloaded the package, but the sample code not working in eclipse .. there is any method.

Comment: Right click your project in eclipse, then choose Add Compatibility library, now you should see android-support-v4.jar under the referenced libraries.

Answer (score 0):

> Now how can i replace the activity under third tab??

You can define tab contents as existing children of the `FrameLayout` (via the `setContent()` that takes a widget ID) or as a dynamically-created `View` (via the `setContent()` that takes a `TabContentFactory`).

Comment: there are two views i.e. one is login view and after login, there is list view . How can i set the view and on button click , how will i call the second view by replacing the view....